# Tuples birthday paradox

Tags: python, algorithm

Tuples is `n`

The birthday problem equation is this:

[image]

Question:

> For n = 200, write an algorithm (in Python) for enumerating the number of tuples in the sample space that satisfy the condition that at least two people have the same birthday. (Note that your algorithm will need to scan each tuple)

```
import itertools

print(list(itertools.permutations([0,0,0]))
```

I am wondering for this question how do I insert a `n` into this?

Comment: Looks a lot like a homework assignment.

Comment: Hey, I want the badge he has :P Just for not being a complete as*****: the problem indicates that `n = 200`, why would you want to use `n`, you actually know the value.

Comment: it is im not asking for answer just how to get n in there

Comment: http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-birthday-paradox/

Comment: The code you give is not ready for a simple "200" addition.  Read the [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) doc: it provides a list without duplication.  Also, you need a list of 200 tuples with integers 1-365; your code prints permutations of 0.

Learn to use the tools you're invoking.  Work out an algorithm to get your desired lists.  Post when you have a problem with your code.

Comment: Yea i took that in, i think n is the number of permutations and tuples is the tuples lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"how to get n in there":

```
n = 200
space = itertools.permutations(bday_pairs, n)
```

I've left out a couple parts of your code:

itertools returns a list; you don't need to coerce it.

Printing this result is likely not what you want with n = 200; that's a *huge* list.

Now, all you need to do is to build bday_pairs, the list of all possible pairs of birthdays.  For convenience, I suggest that you use the integers 1-365.  Since you haven't attacked that part of the problem at all, I'll leave that step up to you.

You still need to do the processing to count the sets with at least one matching birthday, another part of the problem you haven't attacked.  However, I trust that the above code solves your stated problem?

Comment: Thank you thats what i needed:)(new to python).

Comment: yea 200 too big i did smaller numbers now

Comment: Definitely!  I tested with n = 2 and n = 4.  :-)

Comment: `itertools.permutations` does **not** return a list, so if you want to print all generated results you *do* need to convert it. You get an iterator. Looping over that iterator yields items as needed.